# Как вывести выпадающий список в GridView dropdownlist yii2

Tags: yii2

Как вывести выпадающий список в GridView dropdownlist yii2

```
<?= GridView::widget([
            'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",
            'options' => [
                // 'class' => ['gridview', 'table-responsive'],
                'class' => ['gridview', 'table-responsive'],
            ],
            'tableOptions' => [
                'class' => ['table', 'text-wrap', 'table-striped'],
            ],
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'pjax' => true,
            'columns' => [
     [
                    'attribute'=>'status',
                    'format' => 'html',
                    'value'=>function($data){
                        
                       $f =  $form = yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin();
    
    
                      $form->field($data, 'status')->dropDownList([
                            'accepted' => 'Активный',
                            'accepted' => 'Отключен',
                            'callback'=>'Удален'
                        ]);
    
                        yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end();
                        return $f;
     },
                    'label'=>'Статус',
                    'filter'=>['new' => 'Новая запись', 'inprocess' => 'В работе', /*'testing' => 'Тестирование', */ 'callback' => 'Не дозвонился', 'rejected' => 'Отказ', 'accepted' => 'Подключён'],
                    'filterInputOptions' => ['prompt' => Yii::t('yii', 'Поиск...'), 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'status-id']
                ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Поставить `format` -> `raw` (не обязательный шаг к изменению)
2. Внутри анонимной функции воспользоваться `yii\helpers\Html\dropDownList`, который вернёт по итогу `html`